# Dynamic chart allocation QML with cpp

Tags: c++, qt, charts, qml, qtcharts

I have a series of data approx 722 values and I want to plot this data using qml and cpp.
How do I dynamically change the values of x and y axis for line charts ? and how do I append the data ?

I went through the oscilloscope example but it uses a viewer and I am writing a code for the already made GUI can some please help me out ?

QML part:

```
    import QtQuick 2.0
    import QtCharts 2.0
    import QtQml 2.2

    Item {
        id: valueDisp
        implicitWidth: 640
        implicitHeight: 640
        property int currentIndex: -1

        ChartView {
            id: chartView
            title: "Data Output"
            anchors.fill: parent
            legend.visible: false
            antialiasing: true
        }

        Timer {
            id: refreshTimer
            interval: 500 // 60 Hz
            running: componentData.dataUpdated();
            repeat: true
            onTriggered: {
                var lineSeries = chartView.series("Data Output")
                //var x_limit= componentData.dataReadX(currentIndex)
                var i = 0
                console.log("currentIndex;: " + currentIndex)
                if (currentIndex <= 0) {
                    lineSeries = chartView.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeLine, "Data Output")
                    chartView.axisY().min = 0;
                    chartView.axisY().max = 100;
                    chartView.axisX().min = 0;
                    chartView.axisX().max = 100;
                    chartView.axisY().tickCount = 6;
                    chartView.axisY().titleText = "value";
                    chartView.axisX().titleText = "Iteration";
                    chartView.axisX().labelFormat = "%.0f";
                    currentIndex++;
                }

                lineSeries.append(componentData.dataReadX(currentIndex), componentData.dataReadY(currentIndex));
                currentIndex++;

            }
        }
    }
```

PS- `componentData` is an object to access my cpp Q_INVOKABLE functions. I figured out how to pass the data but I am stuck with activating the timer does it need OpenGL as well with it if yes, then how can I activate it ?

Comment: What is `componentData`? For what you need to create new series every 500 ms? Btw, `LineSeries` has `append(real x, real y)` function to add a value. and CPP part of what did you post here?

Comment: I've changed the code and have edited my post